# Is there a way to store hrefs in cookies using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to create a multi-search engine that would also store the user's "favorite" websites, but I can't find a way to store the user's websites (I just want to save website href I'd get in the HTML code) in the cookies and be able to retrieve them when the page is loaded.
My goal is to store some websites that users would "add to his page" to be able to load them when the user loads the page with this code:

```
function add_shortcut() {
    var url = prompt("Please enter a website URL (e.g. nytimes.com) : ");
    if (url != null) {
        websiteName = get_short_name(url);
        document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML += `<figure><a class="single-shortcut" href="https://www.${url}">
            <img src="https://www.${url}/favicon.ico" onerror="this.src='src/img/void.png'">
            <br/><figcaption">${websiteName}</figcaption></a></figure>`
    }
}

function get_short_name(string) {
    string = string.substr(0, string.indexOf('.'))
    string = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
    if (string.length >= 8) {string = string.substr(0, 7) + "..."}
    return string
}
```

The javascript code I use to store everything I keep in cookies:

```
myCookie = {}

function get_expiration_date() {
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
    return "expires=" + new Date(year, date.getMonth(), 28) + ";";
}

function save_cookies() {
    myCookie["sengine"] = detect_search_engine();

    document.cookie = "";
    var cookieString = "";
    for (var key in myCookie) {
        cookieString = key + "=" + myCookie[key] + ";" + get_expiration_date();
        document.cookie = cookieString;
    }
}   

function load_cookies() {
    myCookie = {};
    var key_value = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var id in key_value) {
        var cookie = key_value[id].split("=");
        myCookie[cookie[0].trim()] = cookie[1];
    }

    select_last_search_engine(myCookie["sengine"].toLowerCase());
}
```

***My problem is that I don't know how to get all the hrefs in a div, then put it in a string that I would store in cookies/localStorage to retrieve it and load it when the page loads***...

The whole project on GitHub: https://github.com/Vianpyro/Viaable

Comment: using `localStorage` for a task like this would be more practical. Beyond that , you have shown us a bunch of code but haven't provided a specific problem statement relating to that code and your goal

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, I don't know how to use it yet, I'll see what I can do, thanks a lot for your advice!